# Should you use (x == "x") or ("x" == x) to compare strings?

Tags: c++, string, commutativity

What is the difference between `(x == "x")` and `("x" == x)` comparison in C++? Let's say `x` is a `std::string`. Is there any reason why one would be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is a string literal `"X"`, and the other is an instance of `std::string`. Some advocate having the constant `"x"` on the left hand side, because that way you would get a compiler error if you use assignment `=` instead of equality `==`:

```
if ("x" = x) // Error! Trying to assign to const char[]

if (x = "x") // Setting the value of x to be "x", and evaluating "x". 
             // Probably not what you want.
```

Other than that, there's really no difference.

Comment: Technically trying to assign to `const char[]` I believe.

Comment: This is a bad practice; it decreases code readability. There was a discussion on Programmers.SE about this; I'm trying to find it.

Comment: The compiler writers have noticed this by now, and issue a warning in either case.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is bad practise. I just added it for completeness, hence the "some advocate". Personally, I never write it.

Answer (score 1):

I think both calls will result in call to `bool std::string operator==(const std::string&, const std::string&)`.

This is because there are no implicit conversion operators from `std::string` to `const char*`, but there is implicit constructor from `const char*` to `std::string`.

EDIT:

on g++ 4.4.5 both comparisons works.

Comment: I think the library provides overloads for `bool operator==(const char *, const std::string&)` and `bool operator==(const std::string&, const char *)` rather than relying on the implicit conversion. Of course, there's nothing stopping the overloads from calling the other version.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using for NSStrings...

```
([x isEqualToString:@"x"])
```

or for c strings

```
strcmp(str1,str2);
```

Comment: There is Objective-C++, but I really do not understand people who will prefer to use Foundation classes instead of the C++ Standard Library.